# Delegation method for calling other class

Tags: ios, class, methods, action, delegation

I read different delegation method posts but still I cannot figure out what is wrong.

I would like to show a custom popup (a xib file with its associated popover view controller called **popoverVC**) from my main ViewController (called **mainVC**). Inside my popup there is a button in order to display text in a textfield inside mainVC. My problem is the following:

- the method "firstMethod:" in popoverVC called by my button in Xib file is working (*NSLog message "firstMethod Called!" displayed on the console*)
- this method "firstMethod" calls an other method "secondMethod" located in mainVC. This method is defined in the protocol declaration inside popoverVC and is also working (on the console: *NSLog message "secondMethod Called!" in addition to the previous "firstMethod Called"*).

What I don't understand is that I added a code line in the second method in **mainVC** to display text in a textField (also in **mainVC**) and this is not working (though the previous line with the NSLog command is working).

I have the feeling that since I am creating a new instance of **mainVC** to call the second method in **popoverVC** I am referring to a textfield that is different from the one present in the **mainVC** calling the **popoverVC** at the very beginning. And since NSLog only displays in the console I am on a different viewcontroller.

I fear my explanation is not very clear... Just in case I add my code below.

(My xib file (with its popoverVC class) is called with *textfield beginsEditing* in mainVC)

**popoverVC.h:**

```
@protocol mainVCDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)insertValue;
@end

#import...
```

**popoverVC.m:**

```
//method called by the button in Xib file and supposed to call the method in mainVC to then display text inside a textfield in mainVC

- (IBAction)updateTextFieldInMainVC:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"firstMethod called!");

    mainVC *mvc = [[mainVC alloc] init];
    [mvc insertValue];
    }
```

**mainVC.h:**

```
@interface mainVC : UIViewController <mainVCDelegate>
```

**mainVC.m:**

```
- (void)insertValue {

 NSLog(@"secondMethod called!"); ---> this is displayed on the console

self.textfield.text = @"sometext"; ---> this is not displayed in the textfield

}
```

Comment: Log `self.textfield` and see what it says.

Comment: It is (null)... I don't know how to access it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the important part about delegation. I would recommend reading [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html) on delegation. But in the meantime, here is what you are missing.

Delegation allows popoverVC to be unaware of mainVC. You are creating an instance of mainVC and calling it's method `insertValue` directly, which is not delegation.

In popoverVC.h

```
@protocol mainVCDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)insertValue;
@end

@interface popoverVC : UIViewController

@property (weak) id <mainVCDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

In popoverVC.m

```
- (IBAction)updateTextFieldInMainVC:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"firstMethod called!");
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(insertValue)]) {
        [delegate insertValue];
    }
}
```

In mainVC.h

```
@interface mainVC : UIViewController <mainVCDelegate>
```

In mainVC.m

```
// In init/viewDidLoad/etc.
popoverVC *popover = [[popoverVC alloc] init];
popover.delegate = self;  // Set mainVC as the delegate

- (void)insertValue {
    NSLog(@"secondMethod called!"); 
    self.textfield.text = @"sometext";
}
```

Comment: Answer after the edit is superb.  Probably should just delete the stuff before the edit.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I will read this. But your solution seems not to be working. The insertValue method is not called with [delegate insertValue] in popoverVC. Despite the fact I put popover.delegate = self in the didLoad method of mainVC... There is no more the second NSLog statement :-(

Comment: And I tried to change [delegate insertValue] by [self.delegate insertValue] but it does not work either...

Comment: @Trichophyton - the answer looks right to me. A good-to-know technique about debugging is that you can NSLog practically anything.  So I would, where the popover calls [self.delegate insertValue], NSLog the delegate like this:  NSLog(@"%@",self.delegate);  It should log an instance of mainVC.

Comment: @danh - I did NSLog just after the [self.delegate insertValue] and I noticed that the message is not sent, i.e [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(insertValue)] should return No. I took your advice to test self.delegate and it returns (null), no instance of mainVC is created. I don't know why...

Comment: Sorry it worked! The problem was that I instanciated a new popoverVC in the textFieldBeginEditing method to display the popover in addition to the one in the didLoad method. I first set the delegate in the didLoad method. But by setting it with the good instance of popoverVC it is fine. I think the delegate was set with a wrong instance and it was impossible for popoverVC I interact with to know that mainVC was the Delegate. Thanks to both of you guys!!!